# Android Canvas.drawTextOnPath does not look correct when paint is set to Stroke

Tags: android, view, path, stroke

I have some code setup in an extended view which does some drawings which are easily scaled (vector-like). (My scale is setup as 0-1.0)

I noticed that when I set my paint fill to FILL, the text drawn on a path looks correct, but when I set the fill to stroke (I just want the outline of the text) the image looks like it is on some LSD trip. Here is my sample code :

```
    Paint yellowPaint = Paints.getFillTextPaint(0.01f, 0xFFffea3e, 0.065f);
    canvas.drawTextOnPath(mContext.getString(R.string.building_a_partnership),
             Paths.getRoundedTextPath(mOuterCircleRectF, 280f, 350f),
             0, -0.025f, yellowPaint);

public static Paint getFillTextPaint(float f, int color, float textSize) {
        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        textPaint.setColor(color);
        textPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
        textPaint.setStrokeWidth(f);
        textPaint.setShadowLayer(0.002f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0xFF000000);
        textPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SANS_SERIF);
        return textPaint;
    }
```

If I change the Paint.Style from FILL to STROKE I get the images below. I have used the canvas.drawText() and it works fine showing the stroked letters. It is only when it is applied to a Path, when it seems to get all weird.

[image: Fill Image]

[image: Stroke Image]

Comment: `drawTextOnPath` may not be a supported canvas operation with hardware acceleration turned on. See http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/android-30-hardware-acceleration.html

Comment: Thanks Roman, will check it out.

Comment: So, I tried this instance.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null); did the drawTextOnPath, then did instance.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null); - Does the same thing.

Comment: Does the same thing on my Nexus One.

Comment: OK, my guess is this is indeed a bug (just looked at your code). Mind filing at b.android.com/new? I'll notify our Skia folks

Comment: Submitted http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=26764&thanks=26764&ts=1331581434

Comment: I seen something similar.  It may have to do with scaling after draw along the path. Try not to scale after the draw as a test.

Comment: It turns out that it has to do w/ the scale size being < 1.0

Comment: @Chrispix, I didn't try your code, but I could bet that the issue is related to the size (to big) of the text being drawn. If you look again to what looks like LSD trip, you can identify parts of huge characters. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is due to the fact that my scale factor is 0-1.. There appears to be a bug w/ how rendering a stroke with size < 1.0 is treated.  Suggested solution is to use a scale of 0-100..